# Facebook Api Post Wall When User Offline

Tags: facebook, post

I'm getting the permissions of the user settings page of the application on myfacebook (publish_stream). Even if the user that permits has logged out how can i send something to is wall (as Formspring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/, after the user has logged out of your app/website, all you need to do is user an "**App Access token**" to post to that user's wall as long as you do still have publish_stream permissions for that user.

> **publish_stream**
>
> Enables your app to post content, comments, and likes to a user's
> stream and to the streams of the user's friends. With this permission,
> you can publish content to a user's feed at any time. However, please
> note that Facebook recommends a user-initiated sharing model. Please
> read the Platform Policies to ensure you understand how to properly
> use this permission.